# position:absolute h1 element overflowing right

Tags: html, css

I have a container that has all of the following CSS rules (taken from the Chrome dev toolbar):

```
border-bottom-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
box-shadow: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
display: block;
font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 100;
height: 680px;
line-height: 25.9200000762939px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 411.5px;
margin-right: 411.5px;
margin-top: 0px;
max-width: 1080px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
padding-left: 60px;
padding-right: 60px;
padding-top: 40px;
position: relative;
text-shadow: none;
vertical-align: baseline;
width: 1080px;
```

There is a child `h1` element with these CSS rules:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    top: calc(50% - 21px);
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

However, the text overspills to the right of the container:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

**How can I ensure that the `h1` element snaps to the right hand side of the parent element, without overspilling?**

**EDIT:** The other element, with the iPad image, has the following CSS code:

```
.ipad {
    width: 251px;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url(../img/ipad.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
}
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="canvas">

    <div class="wrapper normal referrals">

        <div style="position: relative;">

            <div class="referrals fade ipad" data-order="1"></div>

            <h1>Referrals</h1>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**How is it that the `h1` element ignores the parent element's padding, but the other element does not?**

Comment: it's position:absolute not display:absolute

Comment: Display absolute is not correct CSS

Comment: @DMande thank you... late nights and silly mistakes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your other element is not overflowing the padding is because it has DISPLAY: absolute in stead of POSITION: absolute;

Create a new div `.container` with `position:relative;`  inside your `div` `.wrapper`.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper normal referrals">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="referrals fade ipad" data-order="1"></div>
        <h1>Referrals</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The h1 element has `position: absolute;` so it does not care if the parent has padding or not. You could solve it like this.

`right: 60px;` where 60px is the containers `padding-right`.

Comment: The element with the iPad image has the same parent and has absolute positioning, and `left: 0;`, so why does that not stick further to the left?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan See user1129884's answer. The edit wasn't there when I answered, sorry.

Comment: Thank you - this still helped me understand the issue!

Answer (score 2):

Your `h1` tag has `position: absolute; right:0` which means that it will be rendered at the rightmost end of the container, which is exactly what happens. If I understand correctly your problem is that you also want to account for the container's padding, in which case you should use `right: 60px;` (since the container's padding is 60px). Alternatively you can use `float:right;` instead of absolute positioning, although how well that would work also depends on the rest of your markup.

Comment: The element with the iPad image has `position:absolute;` and `left: 0;` so why does that take into account the padding?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan the iPAD got `display: absolute;` not `position: absolute;`that's why, also make sure to change that, it's an invalid CSS

Answer (score 1):

you could use right:60px (containers padding-right) or you can create another wrapper inside the first container with position relative